# Entity Framework 5 not loading property

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm working on a EF5 code-first database and it is giving me a lot of trouble on a foreign key. Also sorry if this is already answered somewhere else but I looked at countless of questions on here already and none helped so far.

I have this user class

```
public class User
{
    [Key()]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public CustomClass Custom { get; set; }
}
```

And this custom class

```
public class CustomClass
{
    [Key()]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int CustomClassId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this DataContext

```
public class SilkDbContext3 : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomClass> CustomClasses { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the problem is I can save a PoseAnimation perfectly through the controller. I can also post and update an user with the basic properties (Username, Password), but when I add a custom class to the user, it saves it as a foreign key in the database row, but when I want to retrieve the user, the dbcontext just gives me back null for the custom class (whether I'm retrieving through GET or intellisense). Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to either explicitly or [eagerly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) load the related data, or mark the `Custom` property as virtual if you're using lazy loading.